# Has the 50/50 artifact set distribution in domains ever been tested in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

Recently for "fun(*)" I was looking into some statistical calculation about artifact probability in Genshin Impact.

Currently, getting an Artifact from a domain in Genshin involves ***TEN*** stacked layers of RNG.

- you must get the correct set from the two available in each domain.
- you must get the correct artifact piece from the five possible options (Flower, Plume, Sands, Goblet and Circle)
- you must get the correct Main Stat on the artifact.
- you must get the desired sub stats. Each stat is rolled independently and you can get up to 4 stats.
- (the initial values for those stats is also random so you can get "bad initial values")
- you must level up the artifact and hope that the "bonuses" you get at level 4, 8, 12, 16, 20 are applied to "good" substats.

[This page](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Artifact/Distribution) tried to empirically calculate the actual percentages for different stats on different artifact pieces, showing that statistically "bad" stats are given more weight than "good" ones (for example a main stat Elemental Mastery goblet has a 2.5% chance, compared to 19.5% of an HP% one).

The few calculation done show that you are more likely to win the lottery than getting a "perfect" artifact and getting a "good enough" one can easily take months due to the time-gated nature of domains (you need "resin" to run a domain and you get only a set amount of it).

All the calculation I saw assume that the probability of each set available in a domain is equally split 50/50 between the two sets. Yet, many domains have a "worse artifact" and players constantly report getting the "Bad set" far more often then the "good one".

Obviously, this could be just a form of "failure biases" but given that Hoyoverse already skewed the percentage of bad stats to be higher than good ones, also making good artifact sets less common than useless one seems likely.

Question is therefore simple: **Did anyone ever collect data about common offenders domains (example: Viridiscent VS Maiden) to see if the distribution is indeed biased toward bad sets too?**

---

(*) *where fun actually means "to look in the abyss until it stares back at you"*

Comment: There are no bad sets and good sets. Each set hast different set boni and is thus used in different teams/builds. One set being used more often doensn't make the other one "bad". In your example, Maiden is for Barbara and Viridiscent for Jean, as Barbara needs the healing stat and Jean gains usability by resistance shredding(just like most anemo supports). Also, most 5* chars have one most favorable artifact set specifically made for then in the later versions.

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica even if we ignore later addition like the Clam set (which Barbara would probably prefer over Maiden) I think you can't really argue that most player won't even consider farming artifacts for Barbara in the first place: most player farming Valley of Remembrance want the Viridiscent set - which is still the best option for most Anemo units (while Maid is considered obsolete thanks to Clam in most scenario).

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica the same can be said about things like Lavawalker (very few uses, mostly limited to mono-pyro Klee) VS Crimson Witch (wins every time reactions are involved), or Thundersoother VS Thundering Fury (same problem as Lavawalker, the 2piece bonus being useless and generally being more usable on main dps electro units - which are few if you exclude Raiden who basically requires Emblem).

Comment: Notice that I am keeping this simple here just to start investigating this, but the full picture seem somehow weirder. Many players report Clam being far more generous with Crit Dmg and Crit Rate than average... and that is "(Ko)Komi Can't Crit" set...

Comment: Knowing Genshin, this is a problem that could be solved with money. I am convinced that buying Genesis Crystals increases drop chances across the board. Farming Husk of Opulent Dreams makes me angry, lol

Comment: While I think its possible that the rates for set A and set B might not be 50/50 (say 60/40) per domain (would depend on data). I think its wise to keep saliency bias in mind, i.e. we've all seen threads of people complaining they've lost the 50/50 6 times in a row and that its rigged and then a bunch of people agreeing but never threads saying "I win an above average number of 50/50s" or "I win half my 50/50s" which is not to say these people don't exist (I think I fall into the latter camp) but that its so uninteresting it never gains traction

Comment: @Gatchwar that is kinda why I was trying to find out if anyone actually has tried some serious data collection. You see people claiming the rates aren't equal but that is based just on personal observation - I never saw anyone with an actual big enough dataset. 
That said, something does feel off - farming artifact in a domain often feels like you always get the artifact you don't want. And if you think about it, the game knows what character you own, if they are "built" (see the recommendation system they are adding in next patch)  and what set other players use (the existing suggestion)

Comment: @Neon1024 Since you mention it, I will specify that while I won't be surprised if the rates were skewed towards the less-popular set. But I don't think it is because they want to make you pay - that would not work at all. Think about it: the game lives on the character and the characters need artifact to be strong (compared to their paid gacha weapons artifact are more important).. It seems really stupid to hinder your enjoyment of the product in a game that has no way to make you NEED newer characters (compare to One Piece Treasure Cruise where events almost require the current char)

Comment: @Neon1024 [cont] The more difficult it becomes to make a character usable, the less inclined you are to pull. Maybe you were on the verge of spending to get that new shinny character... but then you noticed that you would have to farm Crimson Witch again and skipped them. Hoyoverse doesn't want that, they have no reason to do that. The only reason to make artifact grind painful is because they think this helps them to make content "last longer". Only issue no one consider grinding content and new regions get 100% by "Idontreadthedialogues" players in two days anyway.